Water filter off of dishwasher line
I’m looking to get a reverse osmosis water filter, but the water line to my sink is inaccessible, would it affect my dishwasher to make a T split in it’s water line and add the filter on that?

Is your dishwasher supplied with hot or cold water?

It is supplied with cold water
